# the form is not processed in spring

Tags: mysql, spring, freemarker

It seems that my program does not process form action. Every time I click on the submit button, the page simply reloads, and there is no entry into the function in @PostMapping at all. Replacing the address in action does not help in any way. Maybe someone has an idea what this is related to?

html of form:

```
<form action="/register"  class="card-back" method="post">
        <div class="center-wrap">
            <div class="section text-center">
                <h4 class="mb-4 pb-3">РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</h4>
                    <div class="form-group mt-2">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-style" placeholder="Почта" id="logemail" autocomplete="off">
                        <i class="input-icon  bi bi-at"></i>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group mt-2">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-style" placeholder="Пароль" id="logpass" autocomplete="off">
                        <i class="input-icon bi bi-lock"></i>
                    </div>
                            
                <button  class="btn mt-4" type="submit">submit</button>
             </div>
       </div>
</form>
```

controller:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RegController {
    private final UsersService usersService;
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepo usersRepo;
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String reg( Model model) {
        System.out.println("регистрация");
        return "reg";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
   public String PostUser (Users users,Model model)
    {
        System.out.println("зашел");
        usersService.createUser(users);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

user model:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column (name = "password",length = 1000)
    private String password;
    @Column (name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="phone_number",unique = true)
    private String phone_number;
    @Column(name = "bDay")
    private java.sql.Date bDay;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;
    
    private char sex;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable (name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles=new HashSet<>();
    public Users()
    {}
    public Users( String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the network tab in the devtools saying? Gets the action-address called, is the body populated? Maybe you have some JavaScript hindering the submit due to potentially input errors?

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to find the cause of this problem. The problem was an incorrect spring security setup: I did not add
`<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}">` to the html login and registration forms file.